# DirectInput 8 linking errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx, directinput, gamepad

I am trying to use DirectInput to control camera movement on a small 3D application for a school project. I am using C++ on VS2010.

Per [this link](http://www.two-kings.de/tutorials/dinput/dinput01.html), I needed to link *dxguid.lib* and *dinput8.lib* on my project properties. So, I added them.

This led to VS2010 not being able to read *dxguid.lib*. Therefore, I had to download and install the DirectX SDK from [Microsoft's download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812). This led to the S1023 error, solved with [Microsoft's solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2728613).

I kept getting other compilation errors, and some searching led me to [this site](http://takinginitiative.net/2010/07/02/setting-up-the-directx-sdk-with-visual-studio-2010/). And after doing that I now only get 2 unresolved externals:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IDirectInput8W
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DirectInput8Create@20
```

This is the relevant code, which was taken from the first link, with minor modifications:

```
bool GamePad::InitDirectInput(void)
{
    if(FAILED(DirectInput8Create(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                             DIRECTINPUT_VERSION,
                             IID_IDirectInput8,
                             (void**)&m_pDIObject,
                             NULL)))
     {
     MessageBox(NULL,
            L"DirectInput8Create() failed!",
            L"InitDirectInput()",
            MB_OK);
    return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And every search I do returns to the same solutions provided above, or similar. I can't find something I haven't done. Can anybody provide an idea? Could the issue be that I am using Windows 8? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I managed to solve the first by using

```
#include <InitGuid.h>
```

But the second persists, to my frustration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your include directories have this entry:

```
$(DXSDK_DIR)include
```

Now for Library directories set the following:

```
$(DXSDK_DIR)lib\x86
```

There is a known problem however with installing visual studio followed by the directx sdk. If the previous suggestions did not solve the problem try de-installing visual studio (make sure you delete the run-time's aswell). And install it again after having installed the directx sdk. Then use the settings I wrote up here and it will probably work (it does for me).

Comment: wow...I had apparently typo-ed the directories.

Thank you very much, sir

Answer (score 1):

I had same error and resolved it by linking with dinput8.lib and dxguid.lib. Interestingly I didn't had to include InitGuid.h.